# How to properly test Czech CSV files for viewing in Excel?

Tags: java, android, excel, csv, character-encoding

I am working on an Android app with several translations, and one feature of the app is to export a CSV file with data.  I am currently working on the Czech translation.  I am based in the United States.

In my code, I set my charset to `Cp1250` for the Czech CSV export.  However, for some reason, when I view my generated CSV file in Excel, Excel renders the file as `Cp1252`, substituting the correct `Cp1250` characters with `Cp1252` characters of the same value.  I even tried changing my Windows Regional Settings to Czech, but no luck.

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?  Should I use a different encoding?  I know Excel works poorly with UTF-8 encoding, so I wonder what would be the best choice for Czech?

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the csv file in excel just to validate the data. You can do the check by opening the CSV file with notepad or notepad++, or if you have to see the data in excel, then import the data using text import wizard in excel.

We use UTF-8 charset to create European data CSV files. It would not open properly in excel if you just open with excel. But once you import using text import wizard in excel the characters will show properly.